# Battery charging time calculation

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, charging

One of the very useful feature of Android version **5.0 Lollipop** is that it shows how much time is left for the charging to be completed. How is the time for the device to get fully charged determined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put it bluntly? Lets say you were charging from 0% to 100%. It would work out how long it takes to charge a certain amount (like 1%, for instance. In reality, it's a significantly smaller number than that) and then uses maths to work out how long it takes to get to 100% (so how long it took that 1% x 100). In reality, it is constantly doing this math as you are charging, therefore keeping the time accurate.

Many things can affect how long it takes to charge our percentage, though. A charge via USB is slower than via plug, and playing a game or watching funny cat videos on youtube in 1080p is going to really slow the charging speed.

Comment: Can you support your answer with credible sources? One might want to  independently verify your claim.

Comment: @Firelord tbh, I'm basing it off calculations I done myself, since the internet has no real answer (unless you count app ads) it'd also be the logical approach to calculating it, understandably.

Answer (score 1):

- As per the training document [Monitoring the Battery Level and Charging State](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html#CurrentLevel) *Determine the Current Battery Level* section describes a method, which I presume is implemented in OS and measured periodically (most likely at every 1% change of battery level)

> You can find the current battery charge by extracting the current battery level and scale from the battery status intent as shown here:

```
int level = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
int scale = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);

float batteryPct = level / (float)scale;
```

- Once you know the current level and the time taken to reach that level, I presume time for full charge is stored in ROM (not sure how and where) it is only a matter of extrapolating

**Note:** This is an educated guess and would welcome inputs